# Need to migrate Existing large Java Swing application running on Linux to IOS(mobile platform)

Tags: java, ios, robovm

I have an existing Large Java Swing GUI application and would like to 
migrate to IOS(Mobile app). Will Java Swing work for sure with robovm?

Just compile to the bytecode on MAC  and run it on IOS, is it 
going to be that simple and there is going to some work involved in it?

Will it support all the 3rd party jars or are there any restriction in it?

Are there any other alternatives on opensource or otherwise simpler for Java Swing GUI application migration to  Mac OS?

Comment: You can never say something (non-trivial) will work "for sure" until you have tried it ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Swing is going to work with RoboVM.  Even if it does, the App Store will very likely reject your app because it won't conform with their UI guidelines.

As far as the non-ui logic in your app, RoboVM should handle it given you're not making native calls.

I know of no Swing to Mac UI converters.  You're probably better off reskinning your app.

Comment: Thanks William/Stephen

Answer (score 1):

[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is very much like Swing and was modeled based on it, it will allow you to port the code relatively easily (layout managers etc.). Porting a Swing app should be trivial see this quick getting started for Swing developers: http://www.codenameone.com/swing.html

Comment: Thanks Shai, Would you have migration guide from Java Swing to Codename One, application is built using Java 6/7 and  has got some I/Os as well.

Comment: You would need to rewrite the application but the port is relatively straightforward for the swing code. For the IO code we still support Input/OutputStream/Reader etc. but all the parsing/file etc. is different since devices are quite different. You would need to adapt quite a few things in the UI for touch and support for high DPI (image resources etc). We now have support for a subset of Java 8 in beta so you can even use Lambdas and stuff.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I source code with 0.5 million line with java swing , reflection,etc used in it. Is it just re factoring like JTextArea to TextArea,etc or it is more to it

Comment: There is a lot more to it. You can't use reflection, code on devices is obfuscated and stripped otherwise your app will way 100mb+ (ARM code is much larger than bytecode). You will also need to adapt UI paradigms to match device behavior not to mention quite a few big things e.g. Table/Tree in Codename One are much simpler than JTable/JTree etc. If you have 500k LoC it would be a lot of work but probably the shortest path among all the options out there. We've helped several enterprise accounts when walking thru the process and its doable.

Comment: Thanks Shai for the input

Comment: I see that codename One was based on LWUIT and has good strong UI base, but for consumer application with complex screens  that goes on the  app store, does it have any norms. Is the output generated from Codename one using Codename UI kit acceptable for any kind of app at the appstore. Please let us know ur views

Comment: Yes. You can build pretty much anything http://codenameone.com/gallery.html the flexibility is limitless and can provide fully native experience